# Verify MySQL Table Creation - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So am I new to PDO and just trying to get my head around it. I have the following code:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare('

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (  
`UserID` INT(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,  
`Username` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,  
`Password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,  
`EmailAddress` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ) ');

$sql->execute();
```

Is there a way to know if the table was created successfully or if it already existed and so wasn't executed?

I know that you can check the ->execute() for a true or false value, but in this instance won't it always be true whether the table was there already or not?

Comment: You could remove the `IF NOT EXISTS` and catch the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. That's exactly what the `IF NOT EXISTS` is for -- to do simply nothing if the table already exists, without triggering an error.

The solution is apparently too obvious to see: Just leave out the `IF NOT EXISTS`. If the table does exist, the statement will trigger an exception (depending on configuration) that you can catch.

Comment: Was somewhat hoping to make it a bit neater so for example if it already exists, they get a simple one line message "Table Already Exists" and if it doesn't and it gets added, they get "Table Added".

Cause at the moment, the way I'm doing it, it says "Table Added" even it it already exists and if I remove the "IF NOT EXISTS" part, then it throws up a horrible load of error rather than just a nice simple one line error.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out:

```
try {

    $sql = $conn->prepare('
        CREATE TABLE `users` (  
        `UserID` INT(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,  
        `Username` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,  
        `Password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,  
        `EmailAddress` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `Rank` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ) 
        ');

        $sql->execute();

        echo "Table 'users' added to the database";

} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    $errors = $sql->errorInfo();
    echo($errors[2]);
}
```